# Diffrence between "perm -mode" &"perm /mode" in find command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I read man page for `find`but it is not clear for me.

`find -perm -mode` ------>at least these bit(s) must be set for a file to match

For example: `find -perm -754` finds 754,755,757,774,777

What about? `find -perm /754`  please explain to me by examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically the difference between all three bits (`-mode`) and any single bit (`/mode`) permission (`-perm`) subset test.

- `find -perm -mode`:

  In this case the permission bits mentioned must be present for the file. For example, if you do `find -perm -666` and if a file has `776`, it will be matched. Similarly `666`, `777` etc will be matched too, but `665` won't be matched. In summary, the mentioned (three) bits must be a subset of the permission bits.
- `find -perm /mode`:

  Here any one bit of subset would do. For example, if we do `find -perm /666`, and if a file has `644`, the file will be matched because the user permission bit is `6`, and we are looking for a single bit subset. Similarly, `700`, `060`, `006` etc will be matched, but not e.g. `444`, as no bit contains any subset of the required permission bits.

Comment: thank you so much. can we say `/mode` is useful for find one portion, for example `find -perm /u=s`?it will find all file with suid?

Comment: @Sinoosh Not quite, both `find -perm /u=s` and `find -perm -u=s` would give you the same result. To spot the difference, add another bit e.g. check  `find /bin -type f -perm '/u=s,g=s'` and `find /bin -type f -perm '-u=s,g=s'`

Comment: Sir,only i have another questions ,in `find -perm /666`  764 will be matched?

Comment: @Sinoosh Spot on. `764` will be matched for both first and second `6`.

Comment: i got it , `-mode` is a part of `/mode` and its result less than `/mode`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer correctly explains the `find -perm -mode` part. However, this answer corrects an incorrect claim about the `find -perm /mode` part.

> Here any one bit of subset would do. For example, if we do find -perm /666, and if a file has 644, the file will be matched because the user permission bit is 6, and we are looking for a single bit subset. Similarly, 700, 060, 006 etc will be matched, but not e.g. 444, as no bit contains any subset of the required permission bits.

The first sentence is true, however, the part claiming `444` would not be matched is not.

`-perm /mode` matches if any permission bit matches, not a whole number.

When passing /666, we are asking the `find` command to look for files that have any of the following bits `rw-rw-rw` (6 = 4+2 which means rw-). So it will match any file that is readable, or writable, or both by any type of owner (user, group or other). That means the only files that will not be matched are files with the following permissions: `000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, `110`, and `111`. Any other permission will be matched by `-perm /666` as it would have either the read or write flags assigned to it.

---

For more clarification, check the following example.

```
for h in {0..7}; \
do for i in {0..7}; \
do for j in {0..7}; \
do for k in {0..7}; \
do \
touch $h$i$j$k; \
chmod $h$i$j$k $h$i$j$k; \
done; \
done; \
done; \
done
```

```
find -perm /666 -printf '%04m %M\n' | grep 444
7444 -r-Sr-Sr-T
6444 -r-Sr-Sr--
5444 -r-Sr--r-T
4447 -r-Sr--rwx
4446 -r-Sr--rw-
4445 -r-Sr--r-x
4444 -r-Sr--r--
4443 -r-Sr---wx
4442 -r-Sr---w-
4441 -r-Sr----x
4440 -r-Sr-----
3444 -r--r-Sr-T
2444 -r--r-Sr--
1444 -r--r--r-T
0444 -r--r--r--
```

So the only thing it does not match are the files that have permissions not containing 2 or 4: i.e. all files that contain only 1 or 0:

```
# remove special permissions (since it was 0 every file that matches and only differs in the set of special permissions is found again)
find \! -perm /666 -printf '%04m %M\n' | grep '^0'| sed 's/ .../ /g'
0111 x--x--x
0110 x--x---
0101 x-----x
0100 x------
0011 ---x--x
0010 ---x---
0001 ------x
0000 -------
```

maybe to clarify a bit:

given the following permissions

- WXYZ: file permissions (e.g. 0755 W=0, Z=5)
- wxyz: search permissions
- w&W is > 0 if at least one bit matches

`/` is an OR operation:
`return w&W || x&X|| y&Y || z&Z`

i.e. return if file contains any permission (W-Z) that matches (at least) the searched permissions (w-z).

while
`-` is an AND operation:
`return w&W && x&X && y&Y && z&Z`

i.e. return if file contains all permissions (W-Z) match (at least) the searched permissions (w-z).

In both cases that can mean that W has set more than w bits
(6 sets 2 and 4, but not 3 or 1)

Comment: actually it answers the question in more detail than the others...

Comment: This answer is correct and touches on an important correction that is made in the other answer. Though it could be edited and salvaged into making a more complete answer.

Comment: I have edited your answer to add more explanation. Feel free to edit it, or revert back. I recommend however you make your example a bit more simple and exclude the special bit as it's not common knowledge for non-advanced users and can make increase confusion a bit.