# Help with find command to identify SUID file please?

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

I am doing an online course and could do with some help please. Please see the image below. I am using find to locate a file with the SUID bit set. The question asks "What is the contents of the file named ‘immersive’, which is owned by user 'linux', with SUID and user execute permissions set? There are multiple files named 'immersive' find the correct one!" From the question I used the command

```
find . -perm /4100
```

I hope that is the correct octal permissions?
In the image you will see two directories returned but when i run ls -la I am not seeing any file with the SUID set. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$ find . -perm /4100
.
./immersive
$ ls .
immersive
$ ls -la ./immersive
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root   23 Aug 20 14:25 ./immersive -> /lib/firmware/immersive
linux@find-command:~$ find . -perm /4100 . ./immersive 
linux@find-command:~$ ls -la 
total 24 
drwxr-xr-x 1  linux linux   4096 Oct 13 13:00 . 
drwxr-xr-x 1  root  root    4096 Oct 11 18:56 .. 
-rw------- 1  linux linux   134  Oct 13 13:00 .bash_history 
-rw-r--r-- 17 linux linux   220  Apr  4 2018 .bash_logout 
-rw-r--r-- 17 linux linux   3771 Apr  4 2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 17 linux linux   807  Apr  4 2018 .profile
lrwxrwxrwx 1  root  root    23   Aug 20 14:25 immersive -> /lib/firmware/immersive
```

Comment: Hi George I dont have a sudo account available to me so I am just running find. The above command gives me a different answer showing me just a . or period. If i then run ls -la I still do not see the file with the SUID bit set. I see linux@find-command:~$ find -user linux -perm /4100
.

Comment: I *think* that you want `-perm /4000` (iirc `/4100` will also find any files with the owner's executable bit set)

Comment: @steeldriver The questions says _"…, with SUID and user execute permissions set"_ so 4100 seems correct.

Comment: Should the`-user linux` option not be included?

Comment: @PerlDuck but the `/perm` form matches *any* of the permission bits, no (i.e. logical OR of SUID and user-executable)?

Comment: When I use the -user option I find only a period, if i then run ls -la on the period, I do not see any files with a SUID set, I guess I am missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/829716/504066) for an explanation of `-perm /mode` vs. `-perm -mode`. I admit, it's not very intuitive, but:

```
find . -type f -name immersive -user linux -perm -u=sx -ls
# or
find . -type f -name immersive -user linux -perm -4100 -ls
```

will do as you ask.

The `-perm -4100` means: find any file that has `4` (=setuid) set AND `1` (=x) set for the user while ignoring the remaining bits (group and other).

The `-perm /4100` on the other hand means: find any file that has EITHER `4` (=setuid) set OR `1` (=x) set for the user (or both) while ignoring the remaining bits.

So `/mode` will find more files than `-mode`.

---

In case it isn't obvious (because I focussed on the `-perm` flag): the others mean: find a *file* (`-type f`) with name `immersive` owned by user `linux`. All these conditions are ANDed.

---

To view the *contents* of the found files you can either `cat` them one by one, i.e. issue

```
cat .../immersive
```

for each found file or let the `find` command do that for you:

```
find . -type f -name immersive -user linux -perm -4100 -exec cat {} \;
```

This will find the files according to the conditions above but instead of printing their names and attributes (`-ls`) will execute the `cat` command for each found file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the difference between -perm and /perm. I have tried both of the above commands but still don't find the file I need. The one with -u=sx gives an error of "unknown predicate -u=sx"

Comment: @user278930 Then you forgot the `-perm`. It must read `find … -perm -u=sx …` where `-u=sx` is a parameter to the `-perm` switch. It looks weird, but is correct. When you drop the `-perm` then `find` thinks `-u=sx` is a switch for `find` and complains but it is actually the parameter for the `-perm` switch. Just like `linux` is the parameter for the `-user` switch.

Comment: Hi PerlDuck just tried both of the above commands, and neither of them finds anything? Am i right in saying the commands are searching the current working directory, which is /home/linux this would seem to fit in with the user in question being linux as well. If I could find this file with the SUID set, how would I view it please?

Comment: @user278930 The proposed commands are correct. And yes, `find .` will find files in the current directory (and below). Are you sure you have a file named `immersive` owned by user `linux` and with the expected permissions? While in `/home/linux` please issue `mkdir -p sampledir; touch sampledir/immersive; chmod 4744 sampledir/immersive` and then run the `find` command again. It should print the name of the file.

Comment: According to the question "The question asks "What is the contents of the file named ‘immersive’, which is owned by user 'linux', with SUID and user execute permissions set? There are multiple files named 'immersive' find the correct one!" It would appear there should be a file.

Comment: Issued your command PerlDuck and then tried the find command again. The output is ./sampledir/immersive. Not sure if I understand what I should have seen, is that right?

Comment: Yes. The `find` command just _finds_ the files and prints their names. Hold on, I'l update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit above PerlDuck, it is not returning anything as the find command still isn't finding anything to cat.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
find / -name immersive 2> /dev/null
```

It will show you all the hidden files as well. Hope this helps