# Help using FIND to find a specific file with an owner and permissions specified

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

in this [SUID thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083469/help-with-find-command-to-identify-suid-file-please) I have some to a grinding halt, with nil success. I need to find a file that is owned by the user Linux, has a SUID set and has user execute permissions set. The file is called `immersive` and I believe it to be in the current working directory of `/home/linux`. I am using this command to try and locate it

```
find . -user linux -name immersive -perm -4100
```

This seems to find precisely nothing and I am at a loss to know what I am doing wrong. I believe the permissions are correct ? I have contacted the learning provider of the course and they have basically told me to read the notes accompanying the course, and suggested to also use GREP. If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `find . -user linux -name immersive` or `find . -name immersive` output anything?

Comment: The first option finds nothing, but the second finds ./immersive  If i then do ls immersive i see another file called immersive in red text, which I take to be a symbolic link?

Comment: If i run ls -la immersive it shows the symbolic link pointing to /lib/firmware/immersive the permissions show lrwxrwxrwx

Comment: Hint: look up what `-L` does in [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: Thanks Muru, but I still cannot see how to incorporate the L switch into the find command?